# remove wcf web service start page

Tags: .net, wcf

I would like to remove, edit, or replace this service page (for lack of a better word). Is that possible? Of course, i still want the service to be available.

I want to at least edit it to remove the "You have created a service..."

The page i'm talking about is this one:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to turn off the [`httpHelpPageEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicedebugbehavior.httphelppageenabled.aspx) in your configuration's service behavior.

Here is an example:

Add the following behavior to your configuration:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="noHelpPage">
      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Assuming you have a service that looks like this:

```
<service 
    name="MyService"
    behaviorConfiguration="noHelpPage" />
```

Note that the `behaviorConfiguration` attribute points to the behavior we just created, `noHelpPage`. Of course, if you have an existing behavior already for your service, just amend it.

Comment: Disable for HTTPS too with:
     <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" httpsHelpPageEnabled="false" />

Answer (score 3):

Mainly for the benefit of anyone else, you can also use httpsHelpPageEnabled if your endpoint is over ssl.  Caught me out today.